# слайдер чисел html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

как вывести над ползунком числа, чтобы было видно что выбирается?
и чтобы можно было выбрать 1 число из 5

```html
<input type=range  id=fader step=20 list=volsettings>
                            <datalist id=volsettings>
                                <option>30</option>
                                <option>45</option>
                                <option>60</option>
                                <option>90</option>
                                <option>120</option>
                            </datalist>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms

Comment: а как указать только 5 чисел?

Comment: пробуйте там - если в js шарите получится - мне лень

Comment: шикарный ответ .

Comment: там можно поставить только шаг, а у меня шаг разный

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form name="myform" oninput="
range1value.value = range1.valueAsNumber;   range1value.style.marginLeft=Math.round(range1.clientWidth * (range1.value / range1.max))+'px';
">
  <output name="range1value" for="range1" >0</output>
  <br/>
  <input id="fader" name="range1" type="range" step="20" list="volsettings" max="200" value="0">
  <datalist id=volsettings>
      <option value="0"/>
      <option value="20"/>
      <option value="45"/>
      <option value="60"/>
      <option value="90"/>
      <option value="120"/>
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Атрибут `max` обязателен, без него не будет отступ считаться.

Comment: а чтобы показывало над ползунком все 5 чисел?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой пример: https://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/rOVrGK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также в datalist можно давать label, но это не везде поддерживается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<input type="range" list="tickmarks" step="10">

<datalist id="tickmarks">
  <option value="0" label="0%">
  <option value="10">
  <option value="20">
  <option value="30">
  <option value="40">
  <option value="50" label="50%">
  <option value="60">
  <option value="70">
  <option value="80">
  <option value="90">
  <option value="100" label="100%">
</datalist>
```

Comment: там можно поставить только шаг, а у меня шаг разный